# Visual Studio 2017 & Docker

Tags: visual-studio, docker

Is there a way to use docker installed on a different machine/server with Visual Studio 2017 during development?

E.g Docker installed on Mac or Linux while Visual Studio on Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very specific, however you can definitely install docker on windows, and there is support for development with Docker and Visual Studio 2017.

> Visual Studio 2017 supports building, debugging, and running containerized ASP.NET Core apps targeting .NET Core. Both Windows and Linux containers are supported.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.2
- https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/